# Javascript es6 syntax support on Netbeans 8.1

Tags: javascript, netbeans, syntax, ecmascript-6, netbeans-8.1

Does anyone know if Netbeans 8.1 has support to es6 javascript syntax and how could I enable it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to use es6 syntax but the editor doesn't recognize it..

Answer (score 4):

No, it is in 8.2, NetBeans 8.2 Release Candidate is available at https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.2/rc/

Comment: I downloaded it, but es6 is not recognized in it, not in highlighting nor in code formatting !!

Answer (score 1):

go to tools -> options -> Miscellaneous 
choose the 'files' tab

If you're missing the 'es6' file extension, then add it manually using the new button. 
Then in the 'Associated File Type (MIME)' choose the same thing you have for js.

That worked for me.

Comment: Hello, did this help for ES6 syntax highlighting and outline, etc.? Currently IDE shows some warnings and even errors, and does not support ES6 syntax correctly.

Comment: @Vlado did you fix it?? I am using netbeans 12 now and like to follow some ES6 Tutorials. =>