# How can I configure NetBeans for full ES6 support

Tags: javascript, netbeans, es6-modules

[image: NetBeans 12 not recognizing ES6 syntax]

I am using NetBeans 12 - although I have the same issue with NetBeans 8. It does not seem to recognize ES6 modules. Is there any configuration/update to remedy this?

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489996/javascript-es6-syntax-support-on-netbeans-8-1) question, but that is specific to NetBeans 8.1 . I am wondering if version 12 has an improvement here.